# Table notes that are compatible with LaTeX2RTF

Tags: tables, footnotes, msword

I want to create a simple table whit a few table footnotes as common in scientific journals. I've tried the package `tablefootnote` and the `threeparttable` but I can't convert them into a RTF document using LaTeX2RTF. What I want is something that looks like [this table](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=929) but I'm pretty certain that I have to be able to get it into Word or the journal wont accept it.

The question: How do I get footnotes right under the table in a way that I can convert it into a Word-compatible format?

#### UPDATE

@Peter Gill's example produces this output in Word:

[image: The footnotes are at the bottom of the page]

I use `R` for creating my tables. Most of the time I use the `Hmisc` latex() function that does a beautiful job but I've found that the [ctable package and other vital packages aren't included](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/latex2rtf-users@lists.sourceforge.net/2011-02/msg00002.html) in LaTeX2RTF and therefore I'm in trouble.

I like LaTeX2RTF since it's very simple to work with but after some more websearching I found [this post](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/converting-from-latex/) where the [Sciweavers](http://www.sciweavers.org/convert-latex-to-rtf) seems to have an implementation that handles footnotes slightly better although complex ctables seem to be an issue. I'll also try to give another try at `tex4ht` package to see if it will handle more complex solutions (how I wish that I could just send all my TeX files without any issues).

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer ("UPDATE 2") into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Ok, I'll change it into an answer but I guess I'll leave @Peter Gill's answer as valid since he made an effort or do you suggest I also change that?

Comment: That's up to you, and adding a self-answer while accepting another answer isn't too uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of testing and looking through the manual for htlatex I've gotten it to work. It's not as intuitive as I would want it but it does an Ok job.

Here's the workflow for getting htlatex to work in Windows 7:

*Installation*

1. Download [tex4ht](http://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-mswin.html)
2. Unzip in a convenient directory (C:\tex4ht)
3. Add path under control panel (System --> Advanced tab --> Env. variables) under "system variables" Path add in the beginning C:\tex4ht\bin\ht\win32;
4. I installed [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) just to on the safe side
5. In the C:\tex4ht\texmf\tex4ht\base\win32 I changed the first entry to the MiKTeX tfm path: iC:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\tfm

*Converting to Word*

1. Press Win+R and type cmd to go to command line
2. Go to the directory with the .tex file
3. Make sure your .tex filename doesn't contain any spaces (this seems to confuse the script even with "")
4. Write `htlatex filename.tex 'html,word' 'symbol/!' '-cvalidate'` to get a html file (it seems to work OK with just `htlatex filename.tex` but it's the recommended syntax, probably for a good reason)
5. Open word and open the html file created by htlatex in the same folder as your latex file
6. Copy and paste the table to any word-document

Here's a sample code of three different ways for creating table footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{Table with footnotes after the table}
  \label{tab:test1}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
  \hline
  column 1 & column 2 & column 3\tnote{1} & column 4\tnote{2} \\
  \hline
  row 1 & data 1 & data 2 & data 3 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1] tablefootnote 1
    \item[2] tablefootnote 2
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Composition of AA2099}\label{2099comp}
  \smallskip
  \begin{minipage}{3.3cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \hline\hline
      Element &  wt\% \\  \hline\hline
      Al\footnote{PHTTTT!!!} &  bal \\
      Cu &       2.69 \\
      Li &        1.8 \\
      Zn\footnote{blahblah} & 0.6 \\ \hline
   \end{tabular}\par
   \vspace{-0.75\skip\footins}
   \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
  
\ctable[caption={Just a ctable},
    label=my_ctable,
    pos=!tbp,
    ]
    {lrccrc}
    {
    \tnote[a]{Over 25 $kg/m^2$}
    \tnote[b]{More than 5 cigarettes/day}
    }{\FL
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries Variable}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Crude}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries }&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Adjusted}
\NN
\cline{2-3} \cline{5-6}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Unadjusted}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Adjusted}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{95\% CI}\ML
{\bfseries Overweight}&&&&&\NN
~~No&1.00&ref&&1.00&ref\NN
~~Yes\tmark[a]&0.74&0.67-0.80&&0.69&0.63-0.76\NN[6pt]
{\bfseries Smoking}&&&&&\NN
~~No&1.00&ref&&1.00&ref\NN
~~Yes\tmark[b]&1.13&1.01-1.27&&1.15&1.02-1.29\ML
}

\end{document}
```

This produces after processing into a Word document:

[image: Converted to MsWord table]

As obvious in the picture there is an issue with the footnotes in table 2 where they end up at the bottom of the page. The `threeparttable` or `ctable` seem to be a better solution.

Comment: Yep, [the `threeparttable` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable) might be a better option. Just used it for the first time for this question regarding [table-notes-next-to-a-table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42175/4301). So if you don't add the additional `minipage` code in the linked example you should get what you desire.

Answer (score 3):

Without the code for your table it is difficult to tell what is going wrong with what you have.

However, if you can include an image (have not tried to convert this with LaTeX2RTF), then this example copied form the link you provided seems to produce a table with footnotes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Composition of AA2099}\label{2099comp}
  \smallskip
  \begin{minipage}{3.3cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
      \hline\hline
      Element &  wt\% \\  \hline\hline
      Al\footnote{PHTTTT!!!} &  bal \\
      Cu &       2.69 \\
      Li &        1.8 \\
      Zn\footnote{blahblah} &        0.6 \\
      Mg &        0.3 \\
      Mn &        0.3 \\
      Zr &       0.08 \\  \hline
   \end{tabular}\par
   \vspace{-0.75\skip\footins}
   \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't posted any code since I'm only interested in a solution that gets the footnotes into Word any way possible. I've tried your code, se my update

Comment: Ok, I've solved the footnotes with the aid of tex4ht as you can see in my latest update. Thank you for your effort, I chose your answer since it was a good answer even though my solution differs some.

Comment: @MaxGordon: I appreciate the thought, but unless you would recommend this solution over what you posted, I think it is not a good idea to accept mine.  Think of someone coming across this question in the future, which one should they focus on first (I would think that would be your solution).

Comment: Ok, I'll set my answer as the right answer.