# Table notes next to a table

Tags: tables, notes

Does anyone have a simple solution for using tables with notes (as in threeparttable's `\tnote`) in a way that lists the table notes on the right of the table, instead of underneath it? I have a table where such a layout would use the available space in an optimal fashion.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem or the desired solution.

Comment: The `tufte` class lets you do this easily. See [here](http://people.ucsc.edu/~weissman/MathClubTalk2009.pdf) for an example and [here](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/) for the project site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without an actual example of what your table looks like it is difficult to say whether this solution will work for you.  But, you could incorporate each portion within a `minipage` to obtain the `tablenotes` besides the table.
Here is a before and after comparison:

### Before:

[image]

### After (with `minipages`):

[image]

### Notes:

- I have not been able to figure out how to get the `tablenotes` section to span the remainder of the column. It seems that [`threeparttable`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable) fixes the width of the `tablenotes` section to match the table (which makes sense in normal usage), but there should be a way to override that and use the entire `\linewidth`.

### Code:

The additional `minipage` code is marked in the MWE example below.
Removing the indicated lines will produce the *Before:* image above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
     \begin{table}%
       \begin{threeparttable}
         \caption{Table caption\tnote{1}} 
         \begin{minipage}{0.10\linewidth}% Added
         \begin{tabular}{ll} 
           \hline 
           Left Column 11 & Right Column 22\tnote{2}\\ 
           \hline 
           Left Column 21\tnote{3} & Right Column 22\\
                            & Right Column 22\tnote{4}\\ 
                            & Right Column 22\\ 
           \hline 
           Left Column 31 & Right Column 32\tnote{5}\\ 
                   & Right Column 33\\ 
           \hline 
           Left Column 41 & Right Column 42\tnote{6}\\ 
           \hline 
         \end{tabular}
         \end{minipage}% Added
         \hfill% Added
         \begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}% Added
         \begin{tablenotes}
            \item[1] Footnote text for caption;
            \item[2] Footnote text for second item;
            \item[3] Footnote text for third item; 
            \item[4] Footnote text for fourth item; 
            \item[5] Footnote text for fifth item; 
            \item[6] Footnote text for sixth item.
         \end{tablenotes}
         \end{minipage}% Added
       \end{threeparttable}
     \end{table}
\end{document}
```